# Python TCP socket.recv() returns with nothing as soon as connection is made

Tags: python, sockets, tcp, client

I'm trying to implement the most basic python TCP server.  Windows 8, Python 2.7, firewall is turned off.  Code is from here: https://wiki.python.org/moin/TcpCommunication

If I do the client stuff (`socket(...), connect(...), send(...)`) via python repl, things work fine, ie the server correctly blocks when calling `recv`.

However if I run the exact same code via python script (both with and without explicitly calling python.exe at windows command line), the `recv` returns immediately with no data.  I read elsewhere on SO this means it's an invalid socket, but I'm not sure what that means or how to check for it.  I'm using the socket returned by `accept()` not the one used to initiate the connection.

I'm trying to block on `recv` so I can take advantage of the timeout (I don't want to use select module, which BTW also returns immediately) and process some keyboard stuff between attempts to `recv`, ie user presses 'q' to quit.

In various experiments I've shown that once this occurs, `recv` will always return immediately (as will `select.select(...)`) if I put it in a loop, so it's not like the client is sending a single "bad" packet initially.  If the client happens to have sent something, then the `recv` returns with that data, but it certainly doesn't block waiting for data when put in a tight loop.

Is this behavior expected?

Server code:

```
import sys
import socket


TCP_IP = '192.168.1.10'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 20  # Normally 1024, but we want fast response

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
s.listen(1)

conn, addr = s.accept()
print 'Connection address:', addr
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE) # This returns immediately with no data, when client connection is run from script and doesn't send() anything, just connects.
    if not data:
        print "broken"
        break
    print "received data:", data
    conn.send(data)  # echo

conn.close()
sys.exit()
```

Client code:

```
import sys
import socket

TCP_IP = '192.168.1.10'
TCP_PORT = 5005
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "Hello, World!"

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
# Commenting out the following to prove the recv() call on the other
#end returns with nothing instead of blocking indefinitely.  If I
#type the rest of this at the REPL the server behaves correctly,
#ie, the recv call blocks forever until socket.send("bla") from client.

#s.send(MESSAGE) data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
#s.close()
#print "received data:", data
sys.exit()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this is expected behavior.

The client does not send anything. And it exit as soon as it connect to the server; cause disconnection.

[`socket.recv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.recv) returns an empty string if the peer performed shutdown (disconnect).

While, in the REPL, the  socket is not closed until you issue `sys.exit()` or you quit the interactive shell.

Comment: Thank you.  I verified this by a) doing a `while True: pass` loop on the client side script, and the server `recv` blocked, and then b) connecting from python repl manually line by line, and the server side `recv` unblocked and passed no data when I did `s.close()` from client side python repl.