# Python - are sockets and recv() blocking by default

Tags: python, sockets

I see a lot of examples online regarding socket recv() that follow this format:

Example from [here](https://steelkiwi.com/blog/working-tcp-sockets/).

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(('localhost', 50000))
s.listen(1)
conn, addr = s.accept()
while 1:
    data = conn.recv(1024)
    if not data:
        break
```

The code here does not set the socket as non-blocking; nor does it set a timeout. My understanding is that `recv()` is blocking by default. If so, how does the code get to the `break` since, if there is no data then it stays on the `recv()`?

EDIT: what is the proper way to handle 'no more data'? Is it to set the socket to have a timeout or be non-blocking; or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20988928/3927528), `recv` could return an empty string (therefore falsey) if the peer shuts down or disconnects. In other words, keep receiving data using the blocking `recv` function until the peer disconnects, then leave the loop.

In response to your edit: generally, if no more data is to be sent, the machine that is no longer sending data would send one last message to tell the server there's no more data to receive, or otherwise just end the connection and you would get your empty string.